# Is there any linux scripts to for uploading nodejs app to myown linux server? Like appfog or heroku

Tags: linux, node.js, scripting, uploader

Is there any linux scripts to for uploading nodejs app to myown linux server? 
Like appfog or heroku. I have dedicated linux server and working on linux too.

I want upload my nodejs application to server and restart nodejs with one shell command. 
I can write script, but maybe don't need to invent bycicle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popular choices using SSH:

- [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/)
- [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.5/)

For serious stuff you really should look at configuration management and server provisioning applications like (in no particular order):

- [Chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home)
- [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
- [Ansible](http://ansible.cc/) (+1 for the name, "Enders Game" is one of my favorite books)

Most revision control systems allows for "after/before-commit" hooks; sometimes I use these hooks to run tests before and automatically deploy to the acceptance environment after commits.

See also [Jenkins CI](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (Continuous Integration is a [hot topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)).

Comment: Good, now i can try this and search analogues. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use [fleet](https://github.com/substack/fleet) from substack to manage deployment. Fleet is a git-based tool that allows you to deploy code and manage your node processes running on remote servers.

Adding in [seaport](https://github.com/substack/seaport) and either [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) or [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) is a great way to build an application that is made up of lots of small components that work together.